# Unable to send email from Ghost - 504 error

Tags: email, blogs, ghost

I performed the simple Digital Ocean ghost droplet setup (Ubuntu 14, Ghost 0.7) and the blog works fine, except the fact that, when I try to invite other authors, I read the following error in the console:

```
http://politidados.io/ghost/api/v0.1/users/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)
```

And, of course, the emails aren't sent.

The same error happens with different smtp configs in the config.js file (I tried mailgun and gmail).

Any help is more than welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Adding more info:

Copying the POST request and using curl gives me:

`{"errors":[{"message":"Unexpected token u","errorType":"InternalServerError"}]}`

Comment: Since it was a 504 error, I added more time to nginx before the timeout with the following lines:
```proxy_connect_timeout       600;
  proxy_send_timeout          600;
  proxy_read_timeout          600;
  send_timeout                600;```

And now the response is 502.

Comment: Still related to sending email: if I instead of logging in click on "Forgot password", it will not send with the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
vendor.min.js?v=b1597048d4:14 TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

After some precious time struggling with nginx configs and ghost configs, I figured it all out:

Digital Ocean blocks SMTP for newly created accounts on certain conditions. That was the case for me.

So all my configs were right from the very beginning - I just needed to send some personal information to the support@digital ocean.

All in all, the digital ocean droplet works fine and all you have to do is to follow these 2 tutorials:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-ghost-application
and

support.ghost.org/mail/

And ask them to lift the SMTP block.